# why the .htaccess file can't rewrite the dynamic url in my website

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

the current is: 
`http://www.vitalimaging.com/about.php?page=overview_vision`

want to clean the url, and here is my code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^about/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ about.php?page=$1 [L]
```

why it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example also has underscore in query string but your regex in `RewriteRule` doesn't include `_`. **Simplify your regex** like this:

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(about)\.php\?page=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^about/([^/]+)/?$ /about.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: This is very trivial rule. Make sure mod_rewrite and .htaccess are enabled and above code is in DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess. Also explain `not working`. Are you getting 404 or what?

Comment: thank you very much for your help.how to enable the mod_rewrite and .htaccess? the .htaccess file is located under the root folder

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks    
RewriteEngine On   
  
RewriteRule ^about/([^/]+)/?$ /about.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

Comment: It won't change the URL in browser since it is doing an internal rewrite. If you want URL to change then add `R` flag like this: `[L,QSA,NC,R]` let me edit my answer also.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is not solved. is there anything else i need do to enable the mod_rewrite and .htaccess?

Comment: the site is hosted by a VDS rented from Godaddy. Do i have to install the Apache to make the .htaccess file work?

Comment: if i type random text, it will give me the internal error page. doesn't that mean the file is working but not working correctly?

Comment: i am using the code you updated. but if you click the link on the top, you will see the code didn't make any change. frustrating

Comment: Do you want `http://www.vitalimaging.com/about.php?page=overview_vision` to turn into `http://www.vitalimaging.com/about/overview_vision` into your browser?

Comment: Try the latest edited answer. If it doesn't work post your complete .htaccess in your question.

Comment: Anubhava, thank you very much! It works. But the funny thing is all of the pages in "about" folder lost the link to the css file. Do you know why and how to fix it?

Comment: That is most common problem people face after switching to pretty URL. You need to use absolute path of your CSS<, JS and images i.e. paths starting with `/` or `http://`

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.